# why is my constructor output on the same line?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java programming.  I've been trying to teach myself by watching videos on youtube and reading books.  I came upon a tutorial about constructors and multiple classes.  I've done everything in the tutorial but my output shows up on the same line, while his is on a different line.
It's driving me nuts and I can't figure out why it's doing this.

This is the code in a class called apples:

```
public class apples{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        tuna tunaObject = new tuna("Neela");
        tuna tunaObject2 = new tuna("Neela");
        tunaObject.saying();
        tunaObject2.saying();
```

And here is the tuna class:

```
public class tuna {
    private String girlName;

    public tuna(String name){
        girlName = name;
    }


    public void setName(String name){
        girlName = name;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return girlName;
    }

    public void saying(){
        System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s",  getName());
    }

}
```

When I run the program i get this in the console window:

"Your first gf was NeelaYour first gf was Neela"

Answer (score 6):

Because your format `String` doesn't include a line separator. I believe you wanted

```
public void saying(){
    System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s%n",  getName());
}
```

instead of

```
public void saying(){
    System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s",  getName());
}
```

The [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) says (in part)

> ```
> 'n'   line separator  The result is the platform-specific line separator
> ```

Comment: o wow thanks. The "n" did the trick.  Thanks so much i can sleep tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

just add **print line** in the middle of this code, 
so the other string will appear on the new line

```
 tuna tunaObject = new tuna("Neela");
 System.out.println();
 tuna tunaObject2 = new tuna("Neela");
```

Comment: I knew about the println.  I was trying to get it to work the same way the guy in the tutorial did, without the println.  Someone pointed out above to use the "n" line separator.  It did the trick.  Thanks for the help guys.